# How to Generate the HTTP Content-Type Header in C?

Tags: c, file-io, http-headers

So I'm working on a networking assignment to produce a basic HTTP/1.0 web server in C. I have most of it figured out, but one of the requirements is that it properly populate the Content-Type field in the header, and I can't seem to find any way to do this automatically.

I'm already using fstat() to get the file size and when it was last modified, and I noticed that also includes a "st_objtype" field, but after some research it looks like this is just the AS/400 object type (which is obviously not what I need) and stat() & lstat() appear to do essentially the same thing as fstat().

Is there any way in C to automatically generate a string with the HTTP-style file type for a given file, or do I just need to make a big list of types and plug the correct value into the header based on the ending of the requested file (.txt, .html, .png, etc)?

Some examples of the Content-Type field for various files I checked:

- `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`
- `Content-Type: image/png`
- `Content-Type: application/x-gzip`
- `Content-Type: application/pdf`

Comment: If you have a *nix based system, see `/etc/mime.types` for a list of known types, or http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some systems contain a file called `/etc/mime.types` which contains a bunch of extensions and MIME type pairs.

See [the documentation for such a file](http://wiki.debian.org/MIME/etc/mime.types).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best approach is a lookup table based on extensions. The idea that a given file has a single "type" associated with it is just wrong. At least using extensions gives you a bit of power to control how the file contents are interpreted. For example if you wanted to show an example of how html source works, you could rename `example.html` to `example.html.txt` and have the client treat it as `text/plain`. If you just used a heuristic to determine that the file contents "are html", you'd be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A file is only a bag of bytes, so there is no way to know for sure that a .html file doesn't contain C code, for example.  You could delegate to the [file command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29), which contains a lot of heuristics for determining these kinds of things based on the first few bytes of a file (scripts start with #!, for instance), but file still isn't foolproof.  I would recommend the lookup table based on filenames.